# LXD containers on default bridge cant be pinged from network or ping to any adress except host

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, lxd

Good Day,

i have following situation, i am during instalation allowed  lxd create bridge lxbr0. actually  containers can contact /ping only host and host can contact/ping containers.containers are not seen on network or they can not acces internal network

my ifconfig on container

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:0f:c5:19
inet addr:192.168.100.120  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:fe0f:c519/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:127 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:1606 (1.6 KB)  TX bytes:6694 (6.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:7743 (7.7 KB)  TX bytes:7743 (7.7 KB)
```

route table on container

```
default         192.168.100.2   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

interfaces on host

```
ens160    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:64:78:f8
      inet addr:192.168.100.1  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe64:78f8/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:60944 errors:0 dropped:4075 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:985 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:5309138 (5.3 MB)  TX bytes:125548 (125.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)

lxbr0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:7b:16:c9:4d:f1
      inet addr:192.168.100.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::30f5:79ff:fe06:1dfd/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:139 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:5252 (5.2 KB)  TX bytes:1298 (1.2 KB)

vethX9FIBG Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:7b:16:c9:4d:f1
      inet6 addr: fe80::fc7b:16ff:fec9:4df1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:139 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:7198 (7.1 KB)  TX bytes:1606 (1.6 KB)
```

route table on  host

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.100.247 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens160
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens160
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxbr0
```

can anyone give me hint ?

Edited Expected behavior is have containers  reachable from local network and containers to be able to reach local network or Internet, containers actualy are not able to install new packager or ever run apt-get update /upgrade/install

Comment: Please specify what the expected behavior is.

Comment: as @Melebius implies: with the current configuration the behaviour would be normal. what behaviour were you expecting?

Comment: expected behavior is  container needs to be seen from internal network where is server connected we had actually two  network 192.168.2.*  where are client workstation or 192.168.1.x where is servers  and i am ever unable to ping containers ip from my workstation or from my another server which is in  192.168.1.x network  so simply remark i need have containers reachable from other local networks